# Квартоплата или квартплата?

Tags: лексика

Возник такой вопрос: как всё-таки правильно? В устной речи встречается слово ***квартплата***: его легче произнести. По сути, оба слова должны быть корректны с точки зрения грамматики: квартплата = квартирная плата, оплата квартиры; квартоплата = квартирная оплата, оплата за квартиру.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Оплата за квартиру" - некорректное выражение (правильно "оплата квартиры" или "плата за квартиру"), поэтому на него нельзя опираться. "Квартоплата" - для меня новое слово, поиском находятся организации под названиями "Квартоплат" (явно образованное без слова "оплата") и "Квартоплата" (обе из Новосибирска). Способ словообразования вызывает риторический вопрос: "квартирная оплата" чего? Обычное слово "квартплата" образовано путём сокращения прилагательного "квартирная" при слове "плата".

Comment: Ой, «оплата за квартиру» вышло случайно.